# What is the best way to implement Tree : LinkedList - Array

Tags: data-structures

I am preparing for an exam, one of the questions I came across is : what is the best way to implement tree, LinkedList or Array.

Most likely: 
- Array uses 1 address 
- LinkedList use two addresses.

Using LinkedList, we can insert the value we need (we manage perfectly the memory), but most likey use O(N) to access to this element, while in Array it O(1).

How should I answer this question ? Or should I just say that is subjective.

Comment: It depends, is the tree a BST?

Comment: We also need to know things like what language we're working in. I.E. is it a language with pointers? What kind of tree, or is it just asking for how to generically implement a *node* class (if the language has classes)?

Comment: If it is a binary tree then use linked list. If it is a BTree with a branching factor as `B`, you can store the keys in a node in an array and the child pointers as linked list.

Comment: Yes ! It's a Binary Search Tree. they said in both C/Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `Binary Search Tree`, the answer would definitely be an array ( at least hopefully an extendable array, like a `vector<>` so you aren't limited to a fixed size). I'll do an analysis of the common operations, **assuming the tree is balanced**.

**Query**

In a BST, nodes need to have pointers to left and right children and is also very common to have parent pointers. In an array implementation, the "pointers" can simply be integer indexes into the array ( this would mean the array would store `Node` objects). Thus looking up the parent and children of a node is constant since indexing into the array is constant. `O(1)`. A linked list implementation would probably need to also  store a reference to the position as to where their ancestors/children are, thus requiring an `O(N)` pass through the list to get the desired references.

**Search**

Starting at the `root`, `array[0]`, searching would be an `O(log N)` operation. Searching would just call/get the info of the children per node, which is O(1) amount of work, roughly O(log N) times, thus `O(log N)` for search in an array.

A linked list would require an O(N) pass through the data to get the required left/right pointers, and can also be done in O(log N) steps, thus producing an `O(n log n)` search in linked-lists.

**Insert**

Arrays would be similar to **search**, except would require  additional `O(1`) constant time for pointer assignments. So `O(log N)` insert.

Linked-lists would also be similar to their **search**  routine, except with an additional `O(n)` time for adjusting the pointers, so `O(n log n)`

**Delete**

Arrays would also be similar to **search**, except you could take more than a single `O(log n)` factor to delete, since you have to traverse back up the tree, but it still is `O(log n).`

Linked lists would too have the `O(n log n)` plus more `O(n log n)` for traversing up. So `O(n log n)` for linked lists as well.

**Conclusion**

The answer should be fairly evident by now :) Plus with arrays you'll get the benefit of better `caching` than linked-lists. Plus, some derivatives of binary search trees, such as `heaps` (usually min-heaps/max-heaps) are commonly represented as arrays,

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) Good luck with that exam!

Comment: In resizing arrays, it might take O(N) for inserting in worst case. Whenever you implement an array based data structure, it is always accompanied by a resizing function as number of elements to be inserted is not predetermined.

Comment: Great point @chettyharish , but then I can do something like table-doubling to make the allocations more efficient. And as I stated at the end, arrays can be cached better than linked-lists.

Comment: Yep arrays are always the best, though table doubling would require copying  all elements from previous array so it be a O(N) operation.

Comment: Should you not be using a linked structure for a binary search tree? Insert would push everything down from an index and in big tree that will have an impact.

Comment: Hi, I don't get why a linked list binary searching tree will be O(n log n) in searching? In worse case it is O(n) (the nodes are all in one side) and usually it is O(log n). 

Also I don't get why insert and delete isn't O(log n) too? Only one parent's pointer needs to be changed. How come it is O(n) to change pointer?

Comment: Wish to get explanation. Thank you! @Alejandro

Answer (score -2):

An `array` is what I'd like to call a fundamental type. That is, it's essentially operating on the raw memory of the system. You can wrap a fundamental `array` with a class to add things like out-of-bounds protection, but you're still going to have to have the raw support for accessing/indexing into a block of memory in anything that isn't assembly.

For a (singly) linked list, in python it would look like this:

```
 class Entry(object):
       def __init__(self, value, child = None)
           self.child = child
           self.value = value

 class LinkedList(object):
       def __init__(self, root_entry = None):
           self.root = root_entry
           self.tail = self.root
           self.size = 1 if root_entry else 0

       def add_entry(value):
           new_entry  = Entry(value)
           if size:
              self.tail.child = new_entry
           else:
              self.root = new_entry
           self.tail = new_entry
           self.size +=1

       ...
```

And so on, you can see that for most operations you simply traverse the root's children till you get where you want to be. Inserting an item simply means replacing that entry's child with the new entry and setting the new entry's child to the old child (and incrementing size)

In general, for singly linked lists element insertion is **O(1)** if you already have the old entry (which you will for most iterators) or at the tail/root. Finding an element by index is **O(n)** as you need to traverse the list, and iterators can only move `down` the list (that is from `index = 0` to `index = size-1`.

Basically all of this information can be studied by simply reading the relevant wikipedia entries. These are all pretty fundamental types that have been around for a very long time.

Comment: You are not answering the question: you are giving general information about LinkedList and BST.

Comment: Which is exactly what his question is, `what is the best way to implement tree, LinkedList or Array.` *Best* is a highly subjective thing. Case in point, `size` for a linked list isn't required to be **O(1)** (and in fact isn't in several implementations) of the pre C++11 standard. The rationale being that you insert elements much more frequently than you query a list's size, so why should you pay the price for keeping `size` up to date on element insertion?